# Blogger: Contempo template have managed to get the posts to post in full but there is still a "snippet" of the post at the bottom of each full post

Tags: blogger

I would like to know how to remove these "snippets" from the bottom of each full post. I'm a new blogger and any help would be appreciated.

See here for example - https://avidreadersretreat.blogspot.com/

TIA.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough, do you want to remove snippet from homepage ? or make it end before these marks «»«» ?

Comment: Neither. You see my full post - go to the bottom of one of the posts and there is a thumbnail and the title again with a link saying read more. I want to remove all of that as I don't need it with having the review there in full above. I hope that is clearer

Comment: I want to know how to remove everything below the "view all my reviews" apart from the post a comment part.

Comment: It's clear now. please upload your template HTML and attach it to question or send it in comment to show you how to remove the undesirable part. you can upload it here and send generated link (no signup required): https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Thank you, Muhammad. I appreciate your help. Here is the link - https://pastebin.com/ieHiHgk1

Comment: You're welcome, I'll add the answer in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Search using `ctrl+F` for `<b:includable id='postBodySnippet' var='post'>` you'll find two results we will work on the second result.

2- Select starting of the mentioned line till nearest `</b:includable>` and replace with these lines:

```xml
<b:includable id='postBodySnippet' var='post'>
  <div class='container post-body entry-content' expr:id='"post-snippet-" + data:post.id'>
    <data:post.body/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
```

3- Don't forget to press `Save Theme` button

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It worked! Muhammad, thank you. I had tried so many different things but none of them worked and I had no idea what to really look for in the code to sort it out. I just followed various "fixes" from google but none of them worked.

Comment: Thanks. You have a nice blog!
Please mark this answer as accepted -if was it. and feel free to contact me next time about your blog fixes. Have a nice day!